# Selenium, JAVA - error in @After

Tags: java, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

My @After function is:

```
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
```

and when I run the test I get an error:

```
java.lang.AddesrtionError: java.langAssertionErrorjava.lang.AssertionError
```

at tear.Down, line:

```
      fail(verificationErrorString);
```

How to fix this one?

Comment: Have you tried using your debugger?

Comment: The function `Assert.fail(String)` will make your test fail. That's the point. So why are you surprised it's failing? Or are you wondering about how it's failing?

Comment: @blalasaadri I am new to test-automation. I haven't figured out these functions in "@After". what should I do?

Comment: Not knowing the exact context I have to guess to an extent, but generally it's rarely a good idea to have a test fail in `@After`. The `tearDown()` function should be used to clean up after tests (e.g. closing the driver), not for testing purposes. So you probably want to move the lines containing `verificationErrorString` to the end of each test. (Could be in a private method you call from every test.)

Comment: I do have these lines at the end of every test.

Comment: please provide body of fail method.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are misunderstanding the purpose of [Assert.fail(...)](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail%28java.lang.String%29) which is *intended* to *cause* a test to fail with the error message passed as a string.  It does this by throwing an AssertionError.  This is working as intended, its purpose is not failure logging.

I'm guessing that you want to report or log the verificationErrorString.  If this is so then add the following to the top of your TestCase class.

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestCase.class);
```

Then replace your *fail(verificationErrorString)* with some thing like

```
logger.warning(verificationErrorString);
```

or

```
logger.error(verificationErrorString);
```

However you could (should) just put those directly in the tests.